# SetAccessRule - Some or all Identity references could not be translated

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl, identity

I have a script that creates a directory and a group in Active Directory. Only users in the group will have access to the directory. Most of the time it works just fine without any problems, but sometimes I get an Exception and I don't know why. Any ideas what the problem is?

My code:

```
[...]

New-ADGroup -Server $adserver -Path $adpath -Description $description -Name $groupname -GroupScope DomainLocal -GroupCategory Security
New-Item -Path $dirpath -Name "$dirname" -ItemType "directory"

Start-Sleep -s 30     #wait to make sure directory is created

$dp = "$dirpath\$dirname"

$Acl = Get-Acl $dp

#fileradmingroup
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($admingroup,"FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar) 
Set-Acl $dp $Acl

#remove inherited permissions
$Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false) 
Set-Acl -Path $dp -AclObject

#new created group $groupname
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($groupname,"DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)     #this is the line where the exception occurs
Set-Acl $dp $Acl

[...]
```

And here is the Exception:

```
Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Some or all identity
references could not be translated."
At L:\Skripte\Skript2.ps1:178 char:9
+     $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IdentityNotMappedException
```

Comment: Is it possible that the group creation has not replicated to the domain controller that the file server uses?

Comment: @AdminOfThings If the script works properly, the permissions of the new directory contain a SID-number. After some time (I think around half an hour) the SID has turned into the name of the new group. So I thought this would not be a problem?

Comment: If full convergence takes 30 minutes, you are only waiting 30 seconds from the time of group creation. Manually create a new AD group using the AD Server stored in your `$adserver` variable. Log into the server that contains the file share you want to configure. See how long it takes for the group to be found in AD from the server when trying to add the group to the file share. If the timing of that group showing up varies, then that is part of your issue.

Comment: Ok, I will try this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same kind of challenge recently when creating new user accounts and home directories in an environment with lots of domain controllers spread over multiple sites. My solution was to use the sid of the newly created account.

I changed the line where the group is created and the line where the access rule is created. The Start-Sleep should not be needed and is commented out.

I hope it works in your situation.

```
$NewGroup = New-ADGroup -Server $adserver -Path $adpath -Description $description -Name $groupname -GroupScope DomainLocal -GroupCategory Security -PassThru
New-Item -Path $dirpath -Name "$dirname" -ItemType "directory"

#Start-Sleep -s 30     #wait to make sure directory is created

$dp = "$dirpath\$dirname"

$Acl = Get-Acl $dp

#fileradmingroup
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($admingroup,"FullControl","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar) 
Set-Acl $dp $Acl

#remove inherited permissions
$Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false) 
Set-Acl -Path $dp -AclObject

#new created group $groupname
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($NewGroup.SID,"DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, Write, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize","ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit","None","Allow")
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)     #this is the line where the exception occurs
Set-Acl $dp $Acl
```

Comment: This solution works great. I have tested it several times over the day and I don't get the Exception anymore. Thanks!